# Erro ao persistir dados no JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Estou a acompanhar exercícios de algaworks do modulo java-ee-7-com-jfs-primefaces-e-cdi-2a-edicao. Ao cadastrar lançamento tenho o seguinte erro:

> ```
> WARNING: #{cadastroLancamentoBean.salvar}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
> javax.faces.FacesException: #{cadastroLancamentoBean.salvar}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     ... 29 more
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
>     at com.algaworks.financeiro.repository.Lancamentos.adicionar(Lancamentos.java:25)
>     at com.algaworks.financeiro.service.CadastroLancamentos.salvar(CadastroLancamentos.java:20)
>     at com.algaworks.financeiro.controller.CadastroLancamentoBean.salvar(CadastroLancamentoBean.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
>     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>     ... 30 more
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
>     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
>     at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
>     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
>     ... 41 more
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'pessoa_id' cannot be null
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     ... 62 more
>
> Nov 01, 2017 6:38:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FacesServlet] in context with path [/Financeiro] threw exception [javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'pessoa_id' cannot be null
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>     at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
>     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
>     at com.algaworks.financeiro.repository.Lancamentos.adicionar(Lancamentos.java:25)
>     at com.algaworks.financeiro.service.CadastroLancamentos.salvar(CadastroLancamentos.java:20)
>     at com.algaworks.financeiro.controller.CadastroLancamentoBean.salvar(CadastroLancamentoBean.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
>     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Comment: E qual o código que lança esse erro? Clique em EDITAR e adicione na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A classe  #{cadastroLancamentoBean.salvar} está tentando salvar um lançamento sem preencher a relação pessoa_id.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a exceção que você postou o erro é violação de constraint

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Column 'pessoa_id' cannot be null
```

Você está inseriando em alguma tabela que a coluna `pessoa_id` é obrigatória, porém o insert tem esse valor nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está tentando salvar o objeto (Lançamento) com o atributo pessoa null. Você deve ter mapeado esse atributo como not null (e/ou criado a coluna not null no banco), por isso a violação de integridade.

Das duas uma, ou você tira a obrigatoriedade deste atributo, ou você atribui alguma pessoa ao objeto de Lançamento antes de salvar.